# MySQL SELECT query only returns one row

Tags: php, mysql

Need help with the below. I want to call all rows concerned yet I only get one.
I have tried all possible methods to output this and all I get is one result from different sessions. The `getID` function calls active session user ID but results are the same for all sessions.

```
    public function getChildId()
{
    $child_id = $this->db->query("SELECT  firstname, lastname
        FROM " . $this->db->table("customers") . "
        RIGHT JOIN " . $this->db->table("genealogy") . " on parent_id
                WHERE parent_id = '". $this->customer->getID(). "'"
    );
   foreach ($child_id as $child => $child_id->num_rows ) {
           $child = array(
              $this->name = $child_id->row['firstname'],
               $this->surname = $child_id->row['lastname']
           );
   }
    return $child;
}
```

}

On `var_dump ($child)` I get: `array (size=2)
  0 => string 'John' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Doe' (length=9)`
I have 3 customer entries/rows on the database

Comment: `on parent_id = ?`

Comment: You're recreating the array on each iteration. You need to define the array outside the loop and add to it within.

Comment: @Sougata Bose. That is where I am joining the tables

Comment: `$child[] = array(......)`

Comment: Yeah, ON parent_id isn't much of a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration you are overwriting or recreating array `$child`, hence at the end you just have only one element (last row of iteration) in array `$child`.

Change

```
$child = array(
              $this->name = $child_id->row['firstname'],
               $this->surname = $child_id->row['lastname']
           );
```

To

( Push one or more elements onto the end of array in each iteration )

```
$child[] = array(
              $this->name = $child_id->row['firstname'],
               $this->surname = $child_id->row['lastname']
           );
```

You can also use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) like below

```
array_push(
           $child,
           array(
                  $this->name = $child_id->row['firstname'],
                   $this->surname = $child_id->row['lastname']
               )
           );
```